# Changing style property with setState in React

Tags: css, reactjs

I feel a bit ashamed to ask you about that because I believe it is quite straightforward to solve this issue and it is basic. But still I stuck on this.

I would like to change my styles, for ex. my backgroundColor, of my div when onscroll event fires, but this seems to be not working. 
While trying to set it like this backgroundColor:this.state.backgroundColor,
the error appears: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Thanks in advance!

Here's my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Header extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            backgroundColor: 'black',
        };
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const headerElement = this.refs.header;
        const sticky = headerElement.offsetTop;
        window.addEventListener('scroll', () => this.handleScroll(sticky)); 
    }

    handleScroll(sticky) {
        if (window.pageYOffset >= sticky) {
            this.setState({
                backgroundColor: 'yellow'
            });
        }
    }

    render() {
        const { containerStyle } = styles;
        return (
            <header style={containerStyle} ref='header'> {this.props.text} </header>
        );
    }
}

const styles = {
    containerStyle: {
        backgroundColor: this.state.backgroundColor,
    }
};

export default Header;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No need to be ashamed to ask questions, I've yet to meet a developer who is not still a student, myself included. :)

Your `styles` variable is out of scope. You need to move it into your `render()` function.

See here for working code: https://codesandbox.io/s/3rynvvn18m?module=%2Fheader.js

Comment: What if you are dealing with a functional component ? I am trying set the css classes directly from the state, but the classes are not changing as expected even when the state changes.

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-morse-hr15t?file=/src/Navbar/Navbar.jsx   I was just trying to build a custom navbar with bootstrap classes using the CDN link. Check the NavBar component. I could see the state change with console,log() but classes remain unchanged. I haven't put all the other code in the sand box.

Comment: You need to add all the code to the sandbox otherwise I only have half the information available.

Comment: I mean I have put all the code required for the navbar component I am trying to create.

Answer (score 0):

Well Just don't move to React without touching basics of typescript. let and const have their block scope and can be accessible only within that block. don't confuse it with var which if declaired outside function then its global.
Don't worry if the above accepted answer makes you feel humiliating.
we all have been there. we do mistake and we do learn.